# Why can I see SSL communication as a plain text in a sniffer?

Tags: wcf, security, http, ssl, sniffing

I've created WCF Service and I share it via ssl. I have little knowledge about security, but I'm curious why can I see whole communication as a plain text in httpAnalyzer, even though POSTs are sending via https?

When my client application invokes wcf service, then I can see it in sniffer - passwords etc.

Does it mean that SSL works only on the lower layer - while transporting data? So every evil application can sniff communication on client's side and an encryption only secures us against man-in-the-middle?

Comment: what kind of sniffer are you using? Some sniffers work at a higher level than ssl (they rely on being on one of the end-points, not on the network), others allow you to install a trusted root certificate they use to MitM your connection. Either way, the endpoint needs to cooperate with the SSL sniffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL works indeed on a "lower layer" than HTTP. According to the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model), SSL works on the Session Layer, while HTTP is on the Application Layer.

Most of these clientside HTTP Analyzers work from within the browser, analyzing the HTTP traffic on the application layer, before it is processed by the SSL logic. So it is completely normal to see the plain HTTP request.

Concerning security, an evil application installed within the browser can indeed read upon the traffic. But once it is processed by the SSL layer, it becomes way harder for an evil application to read the traffic.

SSL works by firstly authenticating the server to you as a client. (Do I talk to the one I really want to talk to). As you can't know all of the servers and their certificates before hand, you use some well known root certificates, which are pre-installed on your OS. These are used to check if some server is perhaps known by an already well known service. (I don't know you, but some really important server tells me that you indeed are who you say you are).

This authentication step works independent from the encryption of the traffic. No program can decrypt an arbitrary SSL stream by "installing a root certificate". (As said these root certificates are already on your machine from the first moment you install an OS on it =)

But if a evil programs is able to let you believe that you are talking to a legitimate server, using a forged root certificate for example, instead of actually talking to malware, it is able to see what the contents of the SSL traffic is. But then again, you are talking to the evil program itself, not the server you were intended to talk to. This is however not the case with HTTP Analyzer

This is in short terms how SSL works and hopefully answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely HTTP analyzer install it's own root certificate, and intercepts SSL traffic, working as man-in-the-middle.